# How to build Tomcat-native for Solaris Sparc 64 bit using 64-bit Java JDK

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, solaris

I'm using Solaris Sparc 64 bit machine. I want to build Tomcat native using 64 bit version of Java. I installed Java in my Solaris box according to [JDK 7 Installation on the Oracle Solaris Operating System](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/solaris/solaris-jdk.html).

When i check the version of Java:

```
/usr/jdk/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/java -version
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
```

I also export `JAVA_HOME`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/jdk/jdk1.7.0_80
```

I configure with:

```
./configure --with-apr=/usr/local/apr/bin/apr-1-config --with-java-home=$JAVA_HOME \
--with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl --prefix=$CATALINA_HOME
```

I am able to build using this java 32 bit but 64 bit java is there in:

```
/usr/jdk/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/sparcv9/java -version
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
```

How do I tell my Tomcat-native configure to use 64 bit java instead of 32 bit java?

---

The issue is here is I can build with 32 bit java and tomcat will work. but in production there is no 32 bit JRE only 64 bit JRE is there. If I use the same 32 bit Tomcat-native library it results in:

```
wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32 (Possible cause: architecture word width mismatch)]
```

**Update #1**

```
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.33 using APR version 1.5.2.
Dec 12, 2015 8:02:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
Dec 12, 2015 8:02:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015)
Dec 12, 2015 8:02:43 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-0.0.0.0-8081"]
Dec 12, 2015 8:02:43 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0-8081"]
Dec 12, 2015 8:02:43 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-0.0.0.0-8444"]
ld.so.1: java: fatal: relocation error: file /tomcat7/lib/libtcnative-1.so.0.1.33: symbol EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name: referenced symbol not found
```

**APR,**

```
 CFLAGS="-m64" ./configure
```

**TC-native,**

```
 CFLAGS="-m64" ./configure --with-apr=/usr/local/apr/bin/apr-1-config --with-java-home=/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.7.0/ --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl --prefix=/tomcat7
```

**Worked!!**
**-----------------------------------------------------------------------**

**build openssl,**

```
export KERNEL_BITS=64
./config shared
make 
make install
```

**Build APR**

```
CC="cc" CFLAGS="-m64" LDFLAGS="-m64" ./configure
make
make install
```

**Build tc-native**

```
CC="cc" CFLAGS="-m64 -fPIC" LDFLAGS="-m64" ./configure --with-apr=/usr/local/apr/bin/apr-1-config --with-java-home=/usr/jdk/jdk1.7.0_80/ --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl --prefix=/tomcat
make 
make install
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't look to be an option to specify a 64 bit sparc target.

Perhaps the build system would figure it by itself from the compiler flags.

I would try:

```
CFLAGS="-m 64" ./configure ...
```

Comment: Thanks, actually this helped me to make some progress.

Comment: But still i'm getting this error in tomcat logs. and tomcat is not starting. please check update #1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29338819/tomcat-openssl-symbol-lookup-error-undefined-symbol-ec-key-new-by-curve-name